# How to use drush with a specific PHP Instance

Tags: drush

What drush command can I use to tell drush to use php 5.6 instead of 7.1 which my  site is currently running on.

A million thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Drush is just a PHP script at heart so all you need is this:

```
/path/to/my/php /path/to/my/drush  ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Alfred. Though I did not really know how you wanted the path implemented. However, I must admit that my question was also vague without stating the environment I am working in. My project is to build the open social using IIS7 and a MySQL server57. I installed composer in windows 10 and thereafter installed the cgr tool which I used to install Drush. Somehow, cgr was no longer in my system. Drush stopped working  after I made php5.6 the default php using the System path. I have had to uninstall drush and  I am reinstalling evreything to get a better environment. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks @ Alfred and leymannx. I was able to make some progress with both answers even though my problem arose from an ill configured environment which I am addressing and after that if I should be able to ask the right question that needs to be asked to sort the malfunction in my open social project